# Using sql command with controller in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
INSERT INTO SaleItem (ProdId, SaleQuantity) SELECT ProdId, BasketProdQuantity FROM Basket;
```

This is my SQL command and I want to use it with a button on a view. But I don't know how to references method with button on view. And should I use `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)` I already connect my DB with WebConfig and it connected as DefaultConnection.

EDIT:
I'm new at MVC and Web coding so I don't know what to do.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buy(SaleItem saleitem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO SaleItem (ProdId, SaleQuantity) SELECT ProdId, BasketProdQuantity FROM Basket";
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Basket");
        }
        return View(saleitem);
    }
```

and there is the view that I want to use buy method.

```
@model IEnumerable<VeriPark001.Models.Basket>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.Book.BookName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BasketProdQuantity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.ProdPrice)
        </th>
        <th>
            Total
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Book.BookName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.MovieDVD.DVDName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.MusicCD.CDName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasketProdQuantity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProdPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @(item.Product.ProdPrice * item.BasketProdQuantity)
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BasketId })</button>
            <button>@Html.ActionLink("Update quantity", "Edit", new { id = item.BasketId })</button>

</td>

    </tr>

}
</table>

<p>
    <button>I WANT TO CALL ACTION HERE. I search for how to do that and couldn't find a proper way.</button>
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Index", "Product")</button>
</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post your current code so we can help you out. There are several ways to perform that query mainly by Entity Framework or by ADO.NET. Also, tag it as ASP.NET MVC if it is.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET MVC web application?  If so, you should probably start with some tutorials.  "reference a method with a button on a view" doesn't really make much sense in that context.  A button would post to an action, and that action can execute whatever server-side code you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Html.BeginForm and send a post request to your controller action.

Replace your

```
<p>
    <button>I WANT TO CALL ACTION HERE. I search for how to do that and couldn't find a proper way.</button>
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Index", "Product")</button>
</p>
```

with

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Buy", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
 {
     // Input for your SaleItem model
     <button class="btn btn-group btn-group-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
 }
```

Since your Buy action requires a SaleItem model I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that I should use SaleItem model or not. I just want to execute a query with button. ^^ Probably my code is all wrong. :/

Comment: You can try the code I suggested even if you didn't put any salesitem. On your Buy action, the saleitem parameter will contain null property values but you added a MoodelState.IsValid so the query  won't get executed. Remove the entire parameter if you just wanna test